# Who is this girl in a blue witch costume and braids cosplaying as?

Tags: cosplay

Could someone help me ID this cosplay?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think its "Wadanohara and the Great Blue Sea"

that is her, I think
[image]